# Excel - Grouping Data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file that contains 1 row for every airline ticket number along with 24 cells of data associated to that ticket. The file needs to go from one row per airline ticket to 12 rows for each ticket. Is there a way to do this without using VB?

Comment: If you have an answer to your question, you can "Answer your own Question"

Answer (score 1):

There is a way! It involves copying blank rows and inserting them in bulk.

First, scroll toward the bottom of the spreadsheet where you have 11 free, blank rows. Where the rows are numbered on the left hand side, click and drag to select all 11 rows. Right click in the grey area and choose copy. (pictured)

[image: excel1]

NEXT, right click on the row number where the second ticket resides (the insert command puts the blank rows above the selected row). In this case, right click on the number 4 on the left side. Choose "insert copied cells".

[image: insertcopiedcells]

Finally, the result gives you an extra 11 rows beneath the first ticket number, resulting in 12 total lines. Continue to do this for each number on the left hand side.

[image: 12 rows per ticket]

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I have over a 1,000 rows so didn't want to do this manually. I ended up using a macro to insert the rows and then used formulas to handle the rest.... thanks